# LED connected to GPIO of the ESP32 never goes off

Tags: led, esp32

I'm using ESP32-WROOM-32D with an LED in this configuration. The LED never goes off in some scenarios when I put the device to deep sleep. I know work-around could be to add a pull down resistor but is there any solution for it without tweaking the hardware?
[image]

```
#define LED 5

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED, HIGH);
  delay(500);
  digitalWrite(LED, LOW);
  delay(500);
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Pull-down won't help. Please post schematic how it's connected and how the board is powered and minimal code to replicate the problem.

Comment: You sure about that schematic? If that were true, that would explain why the LED stays on always. Either through \$R_4\$ or \$Q_2\$. The only difference between the two states is in the brightness.

Comment: I've added only the LED part of the schematics, as far as power is concerned, both LED and ESP are powered by a voltage regulator TPS63805.

Comment: Your schematic has a connection between the colector and the base of the transistor. Is that intended? (If so, then that's the reason for the behavior)

Comment: My bad I didn't see that while recreating the schematic for this post. Removed now.

Comment: Not sure what's going on, but I would try a larger resistor for R4 (e.g. 5k). A floating input may source enough to drive the LED with only 120 Ohms.

Comment: Would there be an issue if the LED is connected to GPIO 14 or 12 of the esp32, I read in the documentation that at startup it's configured as INPUT with pullup?